# window.location.href not redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript

[window.location.href not redirecting to another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfLIG.png)

```
document.getElementById("login-submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
//get user email
const emailField = document.getElementById("user-email");
const userEmail = emailField.value;

//get user password
const passwordField = document.getElementById("user-password");
const userPass = passwordField.value;

if (userEmail == "abc@def.com" && userPass == "123") {
    window.location.href = "./bank.html";
    console.log("clicked");
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Remove dot from `window.location.href = "./bank.html";`

Like this `window.location.href = "/bank.html";`

Comment: I swear to god none of these solutions are working

Answer (score 0):

Just filename is enough.. no need `./filename`

```
window.location.href = "bank.html";
```

Comment: it does not work, even I tried to console a msg with if else condition, it consoles the msg but does not redirect me to another page. It reloads immediately and console msg gets vanished

Comment: If page reload means your `location.href` is working good..Try directly modifying the url bar to navigate bank.html page and see it will navigate to correct page.. is both bank.html and index.html files placed on same folder?